# How to add map application into webpage

Tags: javascript, dictionary, html

I would like to insert [this map](https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/counties-app/) application into my website:

Can anyone tell me if this is possible only by JavaScript? If so, how can this be done?

I would appreciate any answer.

Comment: I think you can do everything with javascript nowadays

Comment: Refer https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_iframe.asp to add it as an iframe in your HTML itself. Easier than dynamically adding with JS.

Answer (score 1):

You can't just copy the code because its copyrighted and you don’t have the CSS3 and JS files that are needed to import it into your site. If you have permission to copy it ask the developers for all files "JS, CSS3" to import the application.